# Implement IDispoable in an Interface

Tags: .net, vb.net, interface

I have a situation where I am defining an interface and then using that directly eg:

```
Dim x as IWhatever = new implementationOfIWhatever()
```

Which is fine, but implementationOfIWhatever also implements IDispoable so I want to be able to do `x.Dispose` or ideally `Using x` but get the error that that this is not declared or must implement IDispoable as IWhatever of course doesn't define Dispose or implement IDispoable.

How can I create the contract that IWhatever will also implement IDispoable or can I not do this and must add .Dispose to my interface and accept I can't use `Using`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make `IWhatever` inherit from `IDisposable`. This will force `implementationOfIWhatever` to implement the `Dispose` method, and it will allow you to use `IWhatever` instances with `Using`.

Comment: I knew it would be something simple, I tried thinks like IWhatever implements IDispoable but not inherits.

Thanks.